# Hive insert with multiple select

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to execute something like this in hive:

```
insert into mytable values (select count(*) from test2), (select count(*) from test3));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to create a hive table with row count as a column?  Assuming that you have to log the row count everyday, I am not sure if we could do this in hive.

But you can try running a shell script something like this if you want a snap shot of the row count of all the tables...

```
$hive -e 'use schema_name; show tables' | tee tables.txt
```

This stores all tables in the database in a text file tables.txt
Now, write a shell script to get the counts of all the tables that were gathered

```
while read line
do
echo "$line "
eval "hive -e 'select count(*) from $line'"
done
```

change the file permissions for the file generated now

```
$chmod +x count_tables.sh
$./count_tables.sh < tables.txt > counts.txt
```

If you are looking for a logging the row count periodically, you can store the rowcounts in a csv, by writing in the values as comma separated values and create an external table pointing to the file.

something like

```
$./count_tables.sh < tables.txt | sed 's/\t/,/g' > counts.txt
```

Hope that's the best way to achieve this

Comment: Your solution is a nice one, however I needed to create Hive tables which store the counts of some other tables (or counts of query results). I did create some linux cron scripts which are being executed every X time and store the counts. I wrote the solution as a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable 
    SELECT c1,c2 FROM
      (SELECT count(*) FROM test2) AS c1
    JOIN
      (SELECT count(*) FROM test3) AS c2;
```

Comment: I have explored this option and I really doubt if this would work. I would be happy if this really works :)

Can you please confirm the actual query and if it was successful please?

Comment: I formed a slightly more complicated query for my own needs that resembles the following:

    `INSERT INTO TABLE mytablehourlystatistics 
        SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),x,y,z FROM
          (SELECT count(*) AS x FROM my_table) AS c1
      JOIN
          (SELECT count(*) AS y FROM my_table where col1 like '%xx%') AS c2
       JOIN
          (SELECT count(*) AS z FROM my_table where col1 like '%yy%') AS c3;`


and it seems to be inserting the records just fine. I was a bit surprised too but as they say, if it works, just don't touch it.